# Why doesn't Anbox work on my laptop (running Ubuntu 17.04)?

Tags: apt, android, adb, android-emulator, anbox

Running `adb install f.apk` produces an error:

```
amdhadul@amdhadul-NSU:~/Downloads$ adb install f.apk
The program 'adb' can be found in the following packages:
 * adb
 * android-tools-adb
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
amdhadul@amdhadul-NSU:~/Downloads$ android-tools-adb install f.apk
android-tools-adb: command not found
amdhadul@amdhadul-NSU:~/Downloads$
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: "Try: `sudo apt install adb`"

Comment: Anbox is 'alpha' software according to [their GIT page](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/wiki/Installation) - you may experience a lot of difficulty in making it run.  Their installation instructions look pretty straightforward.

Comment: @CharlesGreen It looks like the goal here is to install an Android app in an existing Anbox system, rather than to install Anbox itself.

Comment: @EliahKagan It could be  - it's apparent that this is a new Ubuntu user from the attempted installation of  'f.apk' illustrated in the image, and unclear if 'anbox' is actually installed or not.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Well, Anbox can't be installed as an .apk file; it's not itself Android software. If Anbox isn't installed then it will also have to be installed to be used, but the specific error here does not appear to relate directly to an attempt  to install Anbox itself. I'm not really sure if we should close this as unclear or answer it. *Sudu Sh Bash*: Can you **[edit]** this question with a complete explanation of what you are doing? The advice Byte Command gave you should work to address that specific error, but I'm not totally sure right now if that error is all you're asking about.

Comment: @EliahKagan Take it if you feel like it. I have reached my 200+ today anyway ;-)

Comment: @EliahKagan I agree with your assessment:  This looks like it will be an answerable question, but it's not entirely clear what the question is.

Comment: @ByteCommander Sounds good. Answer posted. *Sudu Sh Bash*: I hope this helps. I still recommend you **[edit]** your question to add an explanation of what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

*Install one of the packages that provides the `adb` command. One way is: `sudo apt install adb`.*

Although you've haven't said what you're trying to do with Anbox or why you have run those commands, the specific command you're running that produced the error message is:

```
adb install f.apk
```

`adb install` will not install Anbox, but it can be used to install an app *inside* an Android system that you are using with Anbox.

Ubuntu does not ship with the Android Debug Bridge preinstalled, so the `adb` command is not present on your system until you install a package that provides it. The error message you saw told you that `adb` and `android-tools-adb` packages provide the `adb` command, and that you can install either package by running `sudo apt install <selected package>`, where the text `<selected package>` is replaced with the name of the package you choose to install.

If you have not run `sudo apt update` recently to update the package manager's database of what packages are available from where and in what versions,  I suggest doing so before installing the package.

Therefore, you can install the `adb` package by running these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adb
```

You can also install it however else you prefer to install packages, such as in the Software Center / Ubuntu Software utility or the Synaptic Package Manager.

Once you've installed `adb` you will be able to run that `adb install` command. Whether or not it will *work*, and whether or not it will accomplish whatever you're trying to do, depends on other factors that cannot be discerned from the information you've given. But installing `adb` should completely solve the specific error you have asked about.